# Custom data windows 8 metro app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Sorry if this is something that is easy an i and missing but im the first to admit that im not the best programmer in the world.

What I am looking to do is customise the SampleDataSource that is used in the VS2012 templates, more specifically im looking to replace the ItemContent with the content of a text file.

I have spent many hours looking for a solution to this problem and havent been able to figure it out so though it best to ask the experts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which template have you used?

Comment: I have been using the "Grid App" template this data that the SapleDataSource lay out is perfect for my needs the problem that I am having is that I would like to replace the ITEM_COTENT field of each item with text that I have in a file.

Comment: Are you saying you just want to customize the SampleDataSource provided by the template with your data and it's ITEM_CONTENT field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following post by my fellow Microsoft technical evangelist, Bruno Terkaly:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2012/06/14/how-to-provide-cloud-based-json-data-to-windows-8-metro-grid-applications-part-2.aspx

In the post, he walks through the structure of the SampleDataSource.cs file which provides data for several of the built-in templates in C#/XAML apps, and in a subsequent post (linked at the top of this post) shows you how to replace the existing SampleDataSource.cs with a version that retrieves JSON data via HTTP.

Between the two posts, you may be able to get sufficient background on the topic to accomplish the task you've outlined.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for this I also found a similar tutorial by following the process used to build to Contoso Cookbook app that the evangelists having been using at UK Dev Camps and this seems to be working for me at the moment :)

Comment: The Contoso Cookbook hands-on labs are a nice way to get familiar with a wide range of the features of the Windows 8 app platform. I used the HTML/JS version to connect a lot of the dots when I was getting started, and it helped a bunch. Good luck!